# Use register_rest_field inside a custom route

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I'm currently trying to create an API which will be used to create an app
To do this I need a custom endpoint which should be accessed only from a logged user, which is currently done using this code:

```
register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', 'private/me',array(
            'methods'  =>  WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback' => 'get_private'
));


function get_private($request) {

      $user = (array) wp_get_current_user();
      $user["data"] = (array) $user["data"];
      unset($user['data']['user_pass']);
      // $user = get_user_by('id', 13);
      if (empty($user)) {
            return new WP_Error( 'empty_category', 'there is no post in this category', array('status' => 404) );

      }

      $response = new WP_REST_Response($user['data']);
      $response->set_status(200);

      return $response;
}
```

Currently it return an user object without 'user_pass'

Then when I use the 'register_rest_field' function, I get nothing (the function work if set on any default api user endpoint

```
register_rest_field('private/me',
    'rank_number',
    array(
      'get_callback'      =>  'get_rank_number',
      'update_callback'   =>  null,
      'schema'            =>  null
    )
  );
function get_rank_number ( $user ) {
  return (int) get_user_meta($user['id'], 'ck_user_ranking_score_number', true);
}
```

The thing is, I don't know how to make the route read the list of the registered rest fields nor if it's supposed to be done like that

Currently, I'm trying to make it by extending the WP_REST_Controller class since it looks like it could work

Can someone help me understand how the API work or how it is supposed to be used ? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone have the same problem, a wordpress user answered my post on their forum,

Solution:
The var $wp_rest_additional_fields, I can't find anything about it in the documentation, but at least the var really exist in the global scope

So with this code everything's ok

```
global $wp_rest_additional_fields;

foreach($wp_rest_additional_fields['private/me'] as $key => $value){
      $user_data[$key] = call_user_func($value['get_callback'], $user['data']);
    }
```